# The LastResultOperator result operator is not current supported

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have a query using linq to NHibernate, for `EnterAndExitArchive` entity. This entity has a association by `Archive` entity.

```
public EnterAndExitArchive GetLastEnterAndExitArchive(long archiveId)
{
   var q = SessionInstance.Query<EnterAndExitArchive>()
          .Where(x => x.Archive.Id == archiveId)
          .LastOrDefault<EnterAndExitArchive>();

   return q;
}
```

Or

```
public EnterAndExitArchive GetLastEnterAndExitArchive(long archiveId)
{
   var q = SessionInstance.Query<EnterAndExitArchive>()
          .LastOrDefault<EnterAndExitArchive>(x => x.Archive.Id == archiveId);

   return q;
}
```

But this has a runtime error. Message of exception is `The LastResultOperator result operator is not current supported`.

Why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`LastOrDefault()` is [not supported](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NHLQ-85?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab) in NHibernate.

Maybe you could order the result and use `FirstOrDefault()` instead:

```
public EnterAndExitArchive GetLastEnterAndExitArchive(long archiveId)
{
   var q = SessionInstance.Query<EnterAndExitArchive>()
          .Where(x => x.Archive.Id == archiveId)
          .OrderByDescending(x => x.Something)
          .FirstOrDefault();

   return q;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems the nhibernate Linq provider did not implement `LastOrDefault()` - as a result it is not supported. You can work around this by first of all establishing an order that will return the items you want in reverse order and then using `FirstOrDefault()` instead:

```
var q = SessionInstance.Query<EnterAndExitArchive>()
          .OrderByDescending(x=> x.SomeOrderField)
          .FirstOrDefault<EnterAndExitArchive>(x => x.Archive.Id == archiveId);
```

Also I see you are currently not ordering your results in your query at all - what order did you expect the results to be in? If the order is undefined `LastOrDefault()` is the same as `FirstOrDefault()` ;-)